# Who are the characters in Celeste's developer room?

Tags: game-identification, celeste

In Chapter 6 of *Celeste*, there is a hidden developer room containing various characters. Presumably these characters are from other games by Celeste's developer.

To find the room:

> In Chapter 6, go to the *Reflections* checkpoint to start by a broken elevator. Air dash upward and climb the wall to the next screen. Next, jump and dash up to do a boosted wall-kick off the first small ledge on the left to reach and grab second ledge. Jump towards the right side to find an invisible alcove to recharge your dash. Finally, do a dash-jump across the pit, then dash upwards into another small invisible passage. ([Video demonstration](https://youtu.be/MJfzeUKfdHo))

Who are the characters in this developer room? What games are they from?

[image: Celeste developer room]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*From left to right:*

- Ogmo ([Jumper](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/VideoGame/Jumper))
- Névoa ([Skytorn](http://skytorngame.com/))
- Captain Yuri ([Out There Somewhere](http://store.steampowered.com/app/263980/Out_There_Somewhere/))
- EyeBat ([TowerFall Ascension](http://www.towerfall-game.com/))
- Blue Archer & Pink Archer ([TowerFall Ascension](http://www.towerfall-game.com/))

---

## Ogmo ([Jumper](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/VideoGame/Jumper))

Released in 2004, *Jumper* was one of Maddy Thorson's first games. It is a freeware platformer about helping Ogmo escape an abandoned lab. Ogmo was later featured as an unlockable character in [*Super Meat Boy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Meat_Boy) (2010).

[image]

## Névoa ([Skytorn](http://skytorngame.com/))

Skytorn is an upcoming procedurally generated action adventure game. According to the [PlayStation Blog](https://blog.us.playstation.com/2014/12/06/skytorn-coming-to-ps4/), it is being made by Noel Berry "alongside the developers of *TowerFall Ascension* and *Night in the Woods*".

[image]

## Captain Yuri ([Out There Somewhere](http://store.steampowered.com/app/263980/Out_There_Somewhere/))

A 2012 puzzle platformer from the artists of *TowerFall Ascension*. You play as astronaut Captain Yuri who is trapped on an alien planet. You solve puzzles using a Teleport Gun.

[image]

## EyeBat, Blue Archer, Pink Archer ([TowerFall Ascension](http://www.towerfall-game.com/))

*TowerFall* was Maddy Thorson's first commercial game, released on Ouya in 2013. (Later released on PC & consoles as *TowerFall Ascension*). It is an archery combat platformer with local multiplayer for up to 4 players.

In Towerfall, the [EyeBat](http://towerfall.wikidot.com/enemies#toc4) is an enemy while the [Blue Archer](http://towerfall.wikidot.com/blue-archer) and [Pink Archer](http://towerfall.wikidot.com/pink-archer) are playable characters

[image]

[Credit to NintendoWire](https://nintendowire.com/news/2018/01/30/guide-uncovering-celestes-secret-developer-room/) for their initial list of character names.